# Как сделать чтобы изображение img изменяла размер пропорционально в зависимости высоты другого div блока

Tags: html, css, img

Как сделать чтобы изображение img изменяла размер пропорционально в зависимости от высоты другого div блока и что бы этот блок не наезжал на img.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.cont {
position:relative;  
  height:300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt="">
  <div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S В общем смысл такой, нужно что бы родитель был на всю высоту браузера футер был зафиксирован к низу родителя а изображение занимала всю верхнюю часть и по ширине не выходила за пределы родителя и когда браузер по высоте уменьшается футер не должен наезжать на картинку а она должна ресайзиться пропорционально родителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем тогда позиционировать изображение абсолютно?

UPDATE

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

*
{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
position:relative;  
  height:100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.image
{
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  /* position: absolute; */
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* top: 0; */
}

.footer {
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt=""></div>
  <div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он что делать с тем что footer когда увеличиваешь height начинает наезжать на картинку вместо того чтобы картинка уменьшала размер пропорционально ?

Comment: @RichardB., а за счет чего он увеличивается в высоте?

Comment: В общем смысл такой, нужно что бы родитель был на всю высоту браузера футер был зафиксирован к низу родителя а изображение занимала всю верхнюю часть и по ширине не выходила за пределы родителя и когда браузер по высоте уменьшается футер не должен наезжать на картинку а она должна ресайзиться пропорционально родителя.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zskvqe0k/ попробуйте поресайзить

Comment: То что нужно, благодарю!